# What's the opposite of "oxymoron"?

Tags: single-word-requests, terminology, antonyms

What's the opposite of *oxymoron*? That is, two words put together that seem identical?

Comment: Are you looking for [pleonasm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pleonasm)?

Comment: The opposite of oxymoron would be two words that are perfectly *compatible* with each other, not identical.

Comment: Etymologically speaking, the opposite would be a _moroxyon_. But quite apart from not being an actual word, that would be essentially semantically synonymous with its etymological opposite.

Answer (score 29):

Merriam-Webster says:

> **oxymoron**, *noun* : a combination for epigrammatic effect of contradictory or incongruous words
>
> **pleonasm**, *noun* : the coincident use of a word and its substitute for the same grammatical function
>
> **tautology**, *noun* : needless or meaningless repetition in close succession of an idea, statement, or word

I'm not quite sure how the use of one word can be *coincident* with another per M-W's definition, but looking at [pleonasms.com](http://www.pleonasms.com/), one sees these nuggets:

> anonymous stranger
>
> basic fundamentals
>
> empty hole
>
> ...

I'd say *pleonasm* comes the closest to being the antonym of *oxymoron*, in spirit if not in truth.

Answer (score 8):

Try *tautology*. @alain-pannetier also made a good suggestion in the comments with *pleonasm*. [The Wikipedia page explains the difference](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tautology_%28rhetoric%29).

Comment: As the [wikipedia page for pleonasm explains](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pleonasm), a tautology is very general, whereas a pleonasm is a redundancy in terms. An oxymoron is a contradiction in terms, so it would seem that pleonasm _is_ the  more appropriate antonym. Then again, wikipedia is all made up.

Comment: "redundancy" isn't *quite* an antonym for "contradiction", though...

Comment: @KarlKnechtel That is the problem with the question, though...will add comment to OP.

Comment: Doh, the word "but" is hugely powerful and I should use it with more care. Edited accordingly.

Answer (score 2):

These are nice, but only somewhat related to what I assume the original question is getting at, that is: if a good example of an oxymoron is an expression that involves both a contradiction and an ironic contrast between terms in the expression; the opposite or the reverse of an oxymoron might be an expression which involves an ironic reinforcement between terms in the expression. Neither a pleonasm or tautology assert any sense of irony or humor, as is inherent in an oxymoron.

If "military intelligence" is a good example of an oxymoron, "contempt of Congress" might be an example of the opposite. An oxymoron might give a sense of "these things that don't go together;" the reverse might be the sense of "duh, clearly these are related."

Answer (score -2):

There is no opposite, the word internalizes opposites, its own contradictions. It'd be like making a black & white negative image of a chessboard.

> An oxymoron ... is a paradox compressed into a
>   single self-contradicting phrase, and therefore the show-off among
>   figures of speech. / Helen Vendler, *The Music of What Happens* 1988
>
> ... the discord of the oxymoron. Basil
>   L Gildersleeve, *Pindar: The Olympian and Pythian Odes*

Comment: What are you hoping to tell us? This doesn't seem to answer the question.

Comment: I tried to clean up the answer. I had always been interested in the back story of how the word swiftly become a pet term in the mainstream press in the eighties, perhaps through Vonnegut's and Ashbery's example - and went a bit afield on that.