# Is there any oxymoron word for the word “oxymoron”?

Tags: single-word-requests

I have also asked this in [ELL](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/15243/is-there-any-oxymoron-word-for-the-word-oxymoron), but I'm taking a risk (may be closed very soon) to ask it here again since I'm not getting enough response.

I just have a bizarre thought, though I can't say where will be I using this! So basically *oxymoron* is use of combining of two contradictory terms that would produce a seemingly incongruous meaning.

But can anyone tell me is there a word that "oxymoronifies" (I think I just created that word) the word *oxymoron* itself. [Opposite](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/56338/whats-the-opposite-of-oxymoron) of oxymoron doesn't quite hold the meaning.

I can think of *prominent oxymoron*.

Comment: Is it *pleonastic oxymoron* or *oxymoronic pleonasm*?

Comment: Look up the antonyms for *contradiction* in a [thesaurus](http://thesaurus.com/browse/contradiction). Turn any of them into an adjective. e.g. Accordant oxymoron.

Comment: @MattЭллен Most of the time the answer is not as far as the thesaurus even, it could be right here on ELU.

Comment: How about "tautology," as in oxymoronic tautology/tautological oxymoron?

Comment: I think this is a somewhat *meaninglessly meaningful* (or *meaningfully meaningless*) question. The whole point of the word *oxymoron* is to identify incorrect pairings of ***incompatible*** terms. Depending on how you look at it, the "opposite" of *oxymoron* is either @James's *tautology*, or perhaps a ["stormy petrel"](http://www.satiche.org.uk/satiche/sat-0342.htm) (as in ***fine fettle***, where you almost never encounter any ***fettle*** that isn't ***fine***).

Comment: You could talk about the terms relating to the oxymoron being congruous / congruent, or the oxymoron itself being harmonious. A congruous / harmonious oxymoron would be an oxymoronic phrase in my mind. On the other hand, a 'harmonized' oxymoron would sound like something that originally sounded like an oxymoron but you eventually managed to remove the incompatibility.

Answer (score 8):

**Oxymoron** is Greek for "sharp dull". The word itself is a "oxymoron", so that is your answer. The English word for an oxymoron is oxymoron.