# Can a sentence be both a tautology and an oxymoron?

Tags: grammar, semantics, logic

Sometimes I encounter sentences that are very difficult to unpack into coherent thought. Sentences with tautological double or triple negatives; and sentences where one part contradicts another in grammar or vocabulary.

Since tautologies and oxymorons needn't necessarily operate at the same level of context in a sentence -  *Can a sentence be both a tautology and an oxymoron?*

Comment: We disagreed by general consensus.

Comment: A sentence can _have_ both a tautology and an oxymoron, as pointed out by @mplungjan. I guess it's hard for an entire sentence to actually _be_ a tautology in itself, though; usually that's just one part.

Comment: Could make for a good question with a few examples to drive home your point. "Can a sentence be both a tautology and an oxymoron?" -- Like? And pray, why (would you think) **not** ?

Comment: @Kris Feel free to edit the question for examples, etc. As I don't know firmly one way or the other.

Comment: Incidentally, the editing privilege is not for doing the OP's job. This Q may stand a chance if improved.

Comment: The question of "And pray, why (would you think) **not** ?" still remains.

Comment: @Kris Ok. Let's have this discussion. If some one asks a question of the type _"Can X be Y?"_, then demanding examples of _X as Y_ from the OP assumes they already know the answer. You can not invert the epistemological burden onto the questioner; otherwise they would not be asking the question. Nor can I fathom why you would answer a question _with a question_ (as "comment") on a site with ample mechanisms to post answers. Or simply move on.

Comment: books.google.com/books?isbn=059523206X See also: Le Grice, Malcolm (2002): “Virtual Reality – Tautological Oxymoron”, in Rieser, Martin & Andrea Zapp (eds.): New Screen Media. Cinema/Art/Narrative. London, British Film Institute.

Comment: Possibly related:  http://english.stackexchange.com/q/144417/14666

Comment: "Unless you expect life after death, it's clearly a kind of **oxymoronic tautology** to base a present value on a future event that is of value depending on the present value on which it depends." [emphasis mine] Francisco J. Garcia-Julve - 2011 books.google.com/books?isbn=1462003516

Comment: Starting a question with "Can" or "Is" is bad form, anyway. We want to be able to answer questions with real answers that are not Yes or No. A better question would be: "Where might I find examples of sentences that are both a tautology and an oxymoron?" or "How can I determine if a sentence is both a tautology and an oxymoron?" or "How can I change this sentence so it is both a tautology and an oxymoron?"

Comment: I ate some big jumbo shrimp. I learned military intelligence. This question left me transparently clearly confused. (Tautology involves redundancy.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The sentence

> *Yes, an oxymoronic tautology is possible, because that isn't a contradiction.*

is an oxymoronic tautology.

Comment: Ah. But is the oxymoronic component _"oxymoronic tautology"_? In which case, wouldn't a successful validation of the question mean that _"oxymoronic tautology"_ is no longer oxymoronic? Recursively making the answer both true and false at the same time?

Comment: If it's not a contradiction, then it's not an oxymoron, and the statement is false ... you can take t from there .